# Unit Testing ASP.Net MVC Action result with call to Server.UrlDecode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

We are trying to write Unit Tests in our ASP.Net MVC project.

Some of the methods in the controller contain a call to Server.UrlDecode

This fails with a null reference exception when called from a unit test.

Anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the static HttpUtility class and its UrlDecode method.

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(mystring);
```